# Draw multiple arrows as a bus

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

It's my first post, I've been using LaTeX for some time now but frankly I'm still a rookie.

But this question is more about TikZ than about LaTeX:

I want to draw somehting like this, set of parallel arrows to represent a bus in the digital system, does anybody know to accomplish it?

[image: want to draw this]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTH!

The result:

[image: Bus of arrows between nodes]

And the code:

```
\documentclass [tikz] {standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcounter{mynodes}

% node, begin anchor, end anchor, name
\newcommand{\makepoints}[4]{
    \foreach \k in {1, ..., \points}
    {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\dist}{\k * (1 / (\points + 1))}
        \coordinate (#1 #4 \k) at ($(#1.#2)!\dist!(#1.#3)$);
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        % number of arrows between nodes
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\points}{5}

        % square 1
        \node [draw, minimum size = 2cm] (square 1) {};
        \makepoints{square 1}{south west}{south east}{bottom}

        % square 2
        \node [draw, minimum size = 2cm] (square 2) at (0, -4cm) {};
        \makepoints{square 2}{north west}{north east}{top}

        % arrows
        \foreach \i in {1, ..., \points} {
            \draw [->] (square 1 bottom \i) -- (square 2 top \i);
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, what about node nesting ?

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14052972/Snap%202012-10-18%20at%2015.16.55.png

Comment: I think you just need to draw a node (large box) around the other nodes (boxes inside). You can read in the manual about the `fit` library also, if you are looking for a more elegant solution.